# How to pass Popen objects to concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

As you can see below I have two Popen objects which are running in parallel but on completion of each process I want to perform some postprocess task with the data received from each process individually, but I want the postprocess task to execute in parallel but I get stuck the moment I call the executor.map function and I have observed that the CPU utilisation touches 100% for some time, later it goes down but no result is being achieved. 
I get stuck indefinitely and the process keeps on running. It doesn't even print ***Inside letsee***.

```
subProcess1 = Popen(cmd1, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
subProcess2 = Popen(cmd2, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)

def letsSee(subProcessId):
    print("Inside letsee")
    while True:
        stdoutVar = subProcessId.stdout.readline()
        if stdoutVar == b'' and subProcessId.poll() is not None:
            break
        if stdoutVar:            
            print(subProcessId, type(stdoutVar), stdoutVar)            
        rc = subProcessId.poll()
    return "Yes"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        print("here")
        xList = [subProcess1, subProcess2]
        print(xList) #output is [<subprocess.Popen object at 0x01365290>, <subprocess.Popen object at 0x01365292>]
        results = executor.map(letsSee, xList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this acceptable for you?

```py
def letsSee(command):
    print("Inside letsee")
    subProcessId = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    while True:
        stdoutVar = subProcessId.stdout.readline()
        if stdoutVar == b'' and subProcessId.poll() is not None:
            break
        if stdoutVar:
            print(subProcessId, type(stdoutVar), stdoutVar)
        rc = subProcessId.poll()
    return "Yes"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        print("here")
        xList = [cmd1, cmd2]
        print(xList)
        results = executor.map(letsSee, xList)
```

Comment: @user:12611409 Hi Balaji, sorry for replying to you so late. Thanks for your quick reply, I did try it out on the very same day but the time taken by the the code is almost the same if i do follow the below approach as well.

Comment: ```subProcess1 = Popen(cmd1, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
subProcess2 = Popen(cmd2, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
xList = [subProcess1, subProcess2]
print(xList) #output is [<subprocess.Popen object at 0x01365290>, <subprocess.Popen object at 0x01365292>]
for subProcessId in xList:
    while True:
        stdoutVar = subProcessId.stdout.readline()
        if stdoutVar == b'' and subProcessId.poll() is not None:
            break
        if stdoutVar:
            print(subProcessId, type(stdoutVar), stdoutVar)
        rc = subProcessId.poll()
```
Alternative